# Javascript inheritance with concise prototype assignment syntax

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I've defined two javascript classes using this (`prototype`) approach:

```js
function Parent () {
    this.a = 1;
}

Parent.prototype = {
    hello : function () {
        return "Hello I'm Parent!";
    },
    setA : function (a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
};
```

and

```js
function Child () {
    this.b = 2;
}

Child.prototype = new Parent();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

Child.prototype = {
    hello : function () {
        return "Hello I'm Child!";
    },
    setB : function (b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
};
```

I'm using this technique because I think that the standard syntax it's too verbose and sparse:

```js
Child.prototype.hello = function () {...};

Child.prototype.setB = function (b) {...};
```

The problem here is that I'm *overwriting* `Child.prototype` (inherited from `Parent`) losing `.setA()` method (but correctly *overriding* `.hello()`).

Is **merging the two prototypes** the solution? How?
Can this approach lead to problems?

Comment: Consider this for inheritance: `Child.prototype = Object.create(new Parent());`

Comment: @Matías you can use Object.create or a helper function to prevent creating a Parent instance when setting up the prototype part of inheritance so it should be: `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);` The way you and the OP do it every instance specific member of Parent `this.someting` is put on the Child prototype and (if you do it correctly) immediately shadowed when creating a Child instance (Parent.apply(this, arguments) in Child body). Or worse; programmer assumes that Child has Parent's instance members and doesn't realize they're actually shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is merging the two prototypes the solution?

Yes.

> How?

Simply write a loop that runs over the object literal and merges each property into the prototype.

```
function inherit(Child, Parent, methods) {
    var p = Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    p.constructor = Child;
    for (var m in methods)
        p[m] = methods[m];
    return p;
}
```

```
function Child () {
    Parent.call(this);
    this.b = 2;
}
inherit(Child, Parent, {
    hello : function () {
        return "Hello I'm Child!";
    },
    setB : function (b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
});
```

Comment: For completeness, if Child instances want to have `this.a` assigned with the value of 1 or somehow re use Parent initialize code then in the Child constructor body you should have `Parent.apply(this,arguments);` Often this part is forgotten and OP's sample code doesn't warrant a need for it but I've seen even Crockford complaining about Parent code not being re used when inheriting so it may be worth mentioning that it can be re used.

Comment: @HMR: Thanks for the heads-up, I forgot when mindlessly copy-pasting the constructor. Of course it should be there!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example i copy from pro javascript design pattern

```
function extend (subClass, superClass) {
  var F = function () {};
  F.prototype = superClass.prototype;
  subClass.prototype = new F();
  subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;

  subClass.superclass = superClass.prototype; 
  if (superClass.prototype.constructor === Object.prototype.constructor) {
    superClass.prototype.constructor = superClass;
  } // end if
} // end extend()

function Person (name) {
  this.name = name;
} // end Person()
Person.prototype.getName = function () {
  return this.name;
}; // end getName()

function Author (name, books) {
  Author.superclass.constructor.call(this, name); 
  this.books = books;
} // end Author()

extend(Author, Person);

Author.prototype.getBooks = function () {
  return this.books;
}; // end getBooks()
Author.prototype.getName = function () {
  var name = Author.superclass.getName.call(this);
  return name + " , author of " + this.getBooks();
}; // end getName()

var a = new Author("xxx", "xxx");
console.log(a.getName()); // xxx , author of xxx
```

the author listed three way to implement inherit: class based, prototype based and augment based.

you can read the code and maybe read the book..