# Configuring the [[Prototype]] chain without __proto__

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function to configure the prototype chain, but I want to avoid using `__proto__` directly or `Object.setPrototypeOf`. Can this be done? If not, is either preferable from a performance persepctive?

Also, is it correct to describe this as an implementation of mixins?

This is what I have (uses `__proto__`):

```
function mix(fn) {

   var ancestorFns, curr

   if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
       throw 'fn must be a function.';
   }

   ancestorFns = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
   curr = fn.prototype;

   ancestorFns.forEach(function(ancestorFn) {

       if (typeof ancestorFn !== 'function') {
           throw 'ancestorFn must be a function.';
       }

       curr = curr.__proto__ = ancestorFn.prototype;

   });       

}
```

**Usage:**

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.a = 'a';

function Bar() {}
Bar.prototype.b = 'b';

function Bam() {}
Bam.prototype.c = 'c';

mix(Foo, Bar, Bam);
console.dir(Foo.prototype); // { a: 'a' } 
console.dir(Foo.prototype.__proto__); // { b: 'b' }
console.dir(Foo.prototype.__proto__.__proto__); // { c: 'c' }
```

Comment: Notice that `Object.create(ancestorFn.prototype).__proto__ === ancestorFn.prototype`!

Comment: Just curious: what problems does the current solution cause? (note that asking for *different* solution is in now way wrong according to me or the meta)

Comment: @Begi - Yes, understood, that is on purpose.

Comment: @TomášZato I wish to avoid the performance penalty associated with direct modification of the [[Prototype]].

Comment: @BenAston: But I don't understand that purpose? Why isn't that line simply `curr = curr.__proto__ = ancestorFn.prototype`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure the prototype chain, write to the `.prototype` property of the constructor functions instead of mutating the [[prototype]] of the existing prototype objects. Of course, you'd need to copy all own properties over from the old to the new prototype, that's yhy typically those are only set up after the inheritance process is done.

> is it correct to describe this as an implementation of mixins?

No. Mixins don't mutate the object that is inherited from. Your function doesn't do multiple inheritance (where `Foo` inherits from `Bar` and from `Bam`), but a single inheritance chain (where `Foo` inherits from `Bar` and `Bar` inherits from `Bam`).

And of course your function uses prototypical inheritance, whereas the term "mixin" refers to copying methods onto objects (at least in JS).

> Can this be done?

I'd go by this (rather standard) implementation:

```
function inherit(child, parent) {
    if (arguments.length > 2)
         parent = inherit.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    child.prototype = Object.create(
        parent.prototype,
        // get all property descriptor objects from the old child.prototype
        // will include `constructor` and all manually set properties
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(child.prototype).reduce(function(m, n) {
            m[n] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(child.prototype, n);
            return m;
        }, {})
    );
    return child;
}
```

> Is either preferable from a performance persepctive?

I'm not sure how bad mutating the [[prototype]] of a prototype object really is - if it is done before any instances are constructed. You should test yourself, I'm pretty sure you won't get huge performance differences. Of course, the major drawback of `__proto__` is that it's not supported in all browsers.

Comment: By "rather standard" what do you mean?

Comment: @BenAston: That you can see such kind of `inherit` functions fairly often. Admittedly, the use property descriptors and the recursion are rather fancy than standard, it might as well look like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20230760/1048572).

Comment: PS: Oops, that link references one of my own answers. See other implementations [here](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22function+inherits%28child%2C+parent%29%22), [there](https://github.com/csabapalfi/javascript-patterns/blob/master/legacy-patterns.md#classical-temporary-constructor-pattern), or in [node](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor).